# UIPageViewController: display error when user aborts pangesture

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uipageviewcontroller

Here is my problem: I've implemented a calendar in week mode, navigation between weeks is done using a `UIPageViewController` in pagecurl mode (quite similar to the standard calendar of the iPad). Everything works well except when user aborts the page navigation.
So if the calendar is showing the current week and user pan with the finger to show next week but then aborts the gesture and he doesn't turn the page, the datasource will still display the next week instead of staying at the current week.

I tried using the method

```
        - (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController    
                didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished 
           previousViewControllers:(NSArray*)previousViewControllers
               transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed
```

and detecting when pangesture is aborted and then manually reset the previous viewcontroller but the result is not good at all.

Here is my code for the datasource and delegate methods

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
      viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if (_pageIsAnimating) {
        return nil;
    }    
    [[MCalendarManager sharedCalendar] previousWeek];

    MCalendarContentViewController * contentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CalendarContentViewController"];

    return contentViewController;
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
       viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if (_pageIsAnimating) {
        return nil;
    } 


    [[MCalendarManager sharedCalendar] nextWeek];

    MCalendarContentViewController * contentViewController = [self.storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CalendarContentViewController"];


    return contentViewController;
}

- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController  willTransitionToViewControllers:(NSArray *)pendingViewControllers
{
    _pageIsAnimating = YES;
}

- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
        didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers
       transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed
{

    if (completed || finished) {  // Turn is either finished or aborted
        _pageIsAnimating = NO;
    }

    if (finished && !completed) {//Turn is aborted

        //Do something here for not changing the viewcontroller
    }
}
```

Does anyone has an idea how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: What are you doing in `Do something here for not changing the viewcontroller` ?

Comment: I tried to manually set the previous viewcontroller using the method [self.pageViewController setViewControllers: direction: animated: completion:]; but the result is not good since I still see the viewcontroller changing to the next one before I set the previous again

Comment: You should check the order of the `[[MCalendarManager sharedCalendar] previousWeek];` and `[[MCalendarManager sharedCalendar] nextWeek];` methods are called because if a gesture is aborted and the animation is not completed, one of these methods is already called and in case the animation is aborted you should call the opposite method that was first called, so if `nextWeek` is called then you have to call `previousWeek` and vice versa.

Comment: Of course I ve already tried that, if the animation is aborted, I change the week for matching the previous value. For instance, if I m in the current week and I try to move to the next week and I abort the animation; I will come back to the previous week and set the previous view controller. The problem with that is that I will see the next week changing and then after the previous, the display result is still not good.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand exactly what are you doing, you should edit your question and add a proper example, if posible screenshots for a better understanding, also post the code for the `Do something` part.